# Классы. Калькулятор

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите ,пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы значение last записывалось в атрибут класса, а не в атрибут объекта.

```
class Calculator:
        last = None
        def __init__(self):
            self.history_array = []
       
        def sum(self, a, b):
            self.history_array.append( a + b)
            self.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a + b
        def sub(self, a, b):
            self.history_array.append( a - b)
            self.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a - b
        def mul(self, a, b):
    
            self.history_array.append(a * b)
            self.last = self.history_array[-1]
            return a * b
        def div(self, a, b, mod=False):
            if mod:
                self.history_array.append( a % b)
                self.last = self.history_array[-1]
                return a % b
            else:
                self.history_array.append(a / b)
                self.last = self.history_array[-1]
                return a / b
        def history(self, n):
          
            try:
                result = self.history_array[-n]
            except IndexError:
                result = None
            return result
        def clear(self): self.last = None
```

Comment: А в чём, собственно, проблема? `last` у вас и так является переменной класса

Comment: @Евгений проблема в том, что эта задача проверяется на яндекс.контесте, для проверки просят в конце добавить две строчки
'from classes1_tests import Test
Test(Calculator).run_all()'
и после проверки выходит ошибка, что last не записывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# яндекс это принял

class Calculator:
    history_array = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.history_array = []
    last_operation = None
    @property
    def last(self):
        return Calculator.last_operation

    def sum(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append('sum({}, {}) == {}'.format(a, b, a + b))
        Calculator.last_operation = self.history_array[-1]
        return a + b
    def sub(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append('sub({}, {}) == {}'.format(a, b, a - b))
        Calculator.last_operation = self.history_array[-1]
        return a - b
    def mul(self, a, b):
        self.history_array.append('mul({}, {}) == {}'.format(a, b, a * b))
        Calculator.last_operation = self.history_array[-1]
        return a * b
    def div(self, a, b, mod=False):
        if mod:
            self.history_array.append('div({}, {}) == {}'.format(a, b, a % b))
            Calculator.last_operation = self.history_array[-1]
            return a % b
        else:
            self.history_array.append('div({}, {}) == {}'.format(a, b, a / b))
            Calculator.last_operation = self.history_array[-1]
            return a / b
    def history(self, n):
        try:
            result = self.history_array[-n]
        except IndexError:
            result = None
        return result
    def clear(self): Calculator.last_operation = None

from classes1_tests import Test

Test(Calculator).run_all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Пишите соответственно в поле класса, а не в поле объекта:

```
Calculator.last = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем, как занматься ООП советую почитать вот это: https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/object_oriented_programming.html

Так как Вы явно не до конца понимаете что такое классы и их атрибуты, поля, методы и т.д.

Выделю абзац оттуда:

> Переменные, принадлежащие объекту или классу, называют полями. Объекты могут также обладать функционалом, т.е. иметь функции, принадлежащие классу. Такие функции принято называть методами класса. Эта терминология важна, так как она помогает нам отличать независимые функции и переменные от тех, что принадлежат классу или объекту. Всё вместе (поля и методы) принято называть атрибутами класса.